# Removing backslash from string not working

Tags: swift, string

I'm trying to create the following string: "{ date: '1511764435091' }"

But swift automatically enters backslashes into it like so: "{ date: \'1511764435091\' }"

Searched the web and now i'm doing the following but it doesn't work:

```
    let string = "{ date: '1511764435091' }"

    var editedString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
```

When printing it, this is what I get:

```
(lldb) po string
"{ date: \'1511764435091\' }"

(lldb) po editedString
"{ date: \'1511764435091\' }"
```

Any help?

Comment: If you print string it still contains the same inputed string.

Comment: Just showing that printing both string and editedString returns the same output

Comment: i just use your provided string and run on playground let string = "{ date: \'1511764435091\' }"

print(string)
it shows me { date: '1511764435091' }

Comment: they are just escape characters , to verify just it is working or not, set in somewhere as a text in uilabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html)

> ### Special Characters in String Literals
>
> **String literals can include the following special characters:**
>
> - The escaped special characters \0 (null character), \ (backslash),
>     \t (horizontal tab), \n (line feed), \r (carriage return), \" (double
>     quote) and \' (single quote)

It is clear that `'` is an escaped character. Look at the below code

```
let string1 = "{date: '1511764435091' }"
let string2 = "{date: \'1511764435091\' }"
print("\(string1)")
print("\(string2)")

if string1 == string2 {
  print("Both are equal")
}
```

**Console o/p**

```
{date: '1511764435091' }
{date: '1511764435091' }
Both are equal
```

So you don't need to worry about why there is a `\` before `'`

Why the compiler is not complaining about the quote `'` to be escaped in `let string = "{ date: '1511764435091' }"` is a question. May be apple wants to ease our life, don't know.

Although the lldb shows that the quote is escaped even if you've not escaped in the code.